# SSIS SQL statement with user parameter (int) in a like

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need help with this query in a SQL-task in SSIS

```
select isnull(max(ID+1),991) as ID
from dbo.table
where ID like ?+'%'
```

The user parameter is an int.
ID is an INT.

How will I write to get i right? How to handle an int in the like?

Comment: Column ID data type?

Comment: This query looks very confused. You're treating ID as a `varchar` in the `WHERE`  and a numerical value in the `SELECT`.

Comment: So, hypothetically, if you pass the value `1` are you expecting the values 10-19, 100-199, 1000-1999, etc to be returned (before aggregation). That's what your `WHERE` currently implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the column and the parameters are INT you could CAST them:

```
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE CAST(? AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%'
```

The parameter 1 would match numbers such as 1, 12, 123 etc.